# Jboss 7.1 Ejb3 Struts2 and EAR Can't execute EJB using JNDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, ejb-3.0, jndi, jboss7.x

I am new to EJB and JBoss world and I am facing a problem when trying to execute a stateless bean by its remote interface.

I am doing this in a Struts ActionSupport:

```
public String inscrire() {
    System.out.println("########### Inscrire Action #############");
    Candidat c = new Candidat(nom, prenom, mail, telephone, ecole);
    try {
        final Properties env = new Properties();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.class
                        .getName());
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "UserApp");
        //env.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", "true");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
        InitialContext remoteContext = new InitialContext(env);
        System.out.println("########## Initial Context OK ##########");

        servicecandidat = (CandidatSessionRemote) remoteContext
                .lookup("java:global/EtestEAProject/EtestMetier/CandidatSession!sessions.candidat.CandidatSessionRemote");
        System.out.println("########## LookUp OK ##########");

        if (servicecandidat.inscrireCandidat(c))
            return SUCCESS;
        else
            return ERROR;
    }catch (Exception lookupError) {
        System.out.println("########## LookUp Echec ##########");
        lookupError.printStackTrace();
        return ERROR;
    }
```

The console gives the folowing naming exeption when trying to execute the methode

```
15:01:45,474 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) ########## Initial Context OK ##########

15:01:45,680 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) ########## LookUp Exchec ##########

15:01:45,682 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: global/EtestEAProject/EtestMetier/CandidatSession!sessions.candidat.CandidatSessionRemote -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.global.EtestEAProject.EtestMetier."CandidatSession!sessions.candidat.CandidatSessionRemote"

15:01:45,685 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)     at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:97)

15:01:45,687 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:178)
...........................
```

And the ejb jar deployments says:

```
java:global/EtestEAProject/EtestMetier/CandidatSession!sessions.candidat.CandidatSessionRemote

    java:app/EtestMetier/CandidatSession!sessions.candidat.CandidatSessionRemote

    java:module/CandidatSession!sessions.candidat.CandidatSessionRemote

    java:jboss/exported/EtestEAProject/EtestMetier/CandidatSession!sessions.candidat.CandidatSessionRemote

    java:global/EtestEAProject/EtestMetier/CandidatSession!sessions.candidat.CandidatSessionLocal

    java:app/EtestMetier/CandidatSession!sessions.candidat.CandidatSessionLocal

    java:module/CandidatSession!sessions.candidat.CandidatSessionLocal
```

Comment: Are you remoting from a different JVM? or just a different deployment (or sub deployment) within the same JVM?

Comment: Thanks jyore for you answer i am remoting from A web application using another JVM in the Web Container i suppose....

Comment: I will try to clarify, are the applications in the same jboss instance? are they in the same EAR? or are they on separate machines all together? believe it or not, this determines which JNDI name you use.

Comment: The web and EJB projects are in a EAR project deployed on jboss AS 7.1
EAR EtestEAProject/EtestMetier/CandidatSession

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since your package is as follows:

```
EAR
|-- WAR
`-- EJB-JAR
```

Then the best way to do EJB lookups is:

```
ejb:<app-name>/<module-name>/<distinct-name>/<bean-name>!<fully-qualified-classname-of-remote-interface>
```

In your case:

```
ejb:EtestEAProject/EtestMetier//CandidatSession!sessions.candidat.CandidatSessionRemote
```

Yes, the '//' is correct, as distinct name is an empty string.

A method that gets does the lookup should be something like:

```
public CandidatSessionRemote getEJB() {
    Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
    jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
    return (CandidateSessionRemote) context.lookup("ejb:EtestEAProject/EtestMetier//CandidatSession!sessions.candidat.CandidatSessionRemote");
}
```

Hope this helps and please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: @Lord-zed, was this answer helpful? If so, please accept the answer. If not, please let me know why and I can try to help further.

Comment: If you're in the same EAR you can (should?) use local interfaces. At least on AS 6 and before, a default initial context (without parameters) is sufficient to lookup the bean. The JBoss specific ejb: namespace should not be needed locally. Java EE has portable names for local beans that even "rebel AS" JBoss AS 7 had to implement.